# $17!=3556xy428096000,$then $(x+y)$ equals?(without using a calculator)

Tags: numerical-methods

$17!=3556xy428096000,$then **$(x+y)$** equals?

a)$15$ b)$6$ c)$12$ d)$13$

With help of calculator $(x+y)$ can be easily calculated as **$15$**.But without a calculator,I can only conclude that the sum of digits $(3+5+5+6+x+y+4+2+8+9+6)$ is a **multiple of $3$**, & excluding $(x+y)$ the sum of the digits $(3+5+5+6+4+2+8+9+6) =48$.Thus excluding option d) the ans can be any of a),b) or c).

Please help me to find the exact answer.

**Thank you**

Comment: I feel certain that this is a duplicate.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but [closely related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/521588/28900).

Comment: I am also quite sure that there have been questions that use precisely the same technique. A very large proportion of "new" MSE questions are essentially duplicates.

Comment: This is more number-theory than numerical-methods, surely.  @Cameron: Did you find a duplicate?  ETA: OK, I see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use the fact that the factorial is divisible by $9$, and therefore the digit sum is divisible by $9$.

Then use the fact that the number with decimal representation $abcdefg\dots$ is divisible by $11$ if and only if $a-b+c-d+e-f+\cdots$ is divisible by $11$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the number was copied incorrectly (somehow) and it was driving me crazy trying to figure out what I was doing wrong.

Since $17 > 13$, $17!$ must be divisible by $7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 = 1001$.  That means if we take the digits preceding the trailing zeros, and place them in groups of three, like so—$355, 6\text{XY}, 428, 096$—the alternating sums must be the same modulo $1001$.  We have, then,

$$
355+428 = 6\text{XY}+96
$$

and then $\text{XY} = 87$.

Answer (score 0):

Testing divisibility by 9 gives
$$
48 + x + y \equiv 0 \pmod {9}.
$$
Testing divisibility by 11 gives
$$
12 - x + y \equiv 0 \pmod {11}
$$
So $x - y \equiv 1 \pmod {11}$ and $x + y \equiv 6 \pmod{9}$.
Since $x, y$ are both digits, $x = 1 + y$, and $x + y$ is odd.